# How to get hex of IEEE 754 float in shell

Tags: floating-point, hex, sh

I want to get HEX representation of float number in Shell script.
I found lot's of example from hex to float but not a single one other way.

Sadly printf can't do that.

```
printf %x needs decimal.
printf "%x\n" "4.0"
sh: invalid number '4.0'
```

I don't have gdb, python, perl, bash, od nor crackNum on this embedded system.

I have hexdump, hexedit or bc.

I'm going to make custom C utility that only thing that it does, is prints hex value from float, but I would like to know if I can do it in sh.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way of doing it in plain sh, you better start writing that custom utility.

Comment: I have been building some utilities like this recently and AFAIK a C program (or the equivalent) is the only way.